# Checking if command line input is an integer

Tags: c++, console

The code below accepts 1 command line argument from the user. The expected input is an integer. Hence, the code checks if the input is purely an integer. Any feedback is appreciated.

`atoi()` does not provide error-checking, thus the idea is to verify the input before passing the input to `atoi()`.

I considered using `strtol()`, but it looks way too complex for a simple task.

`stoi()` considers `1a` as valid, which is not valid in my use case.

```
//abc   ->  Invalid
//1a    ->  Invalid
//a1    ->  Invalid
//1     ->  Valid 

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;

int correctInput;
string userInputStr;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    userInputStr = argv[1];
    for ( int x = 0; x < userInputStr.length(); x++)
    {
        if ( isalpha(userInputStr[x]) )
        {
            cout << "invalid input." << endl;
            return 0;
        }

    }

    correctInput = atoi(userInputStr.c_str());

    cout << correctInput << endl;

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`strtol` will work just fine for this job:

```
char *end;
int correctInput = strtol(argv[1], &end, 10);

if (*end != '\0') {
    std::cout << "invalid input.\n";
    return 1;
}
std::cout << correctInput << "\n";
```

That said, let's do a quick review of your existing code.

## Avoid `using namespace std;`

This is common in quite a few tutorials and such, largely of the sake of brevity. In any case, it's generally best avoided in real code.

## Avoid global variables

Right now, you've defined `correctInput` and `userInputString` as global variables, even though they're only used inside of `main`. As a general rule of thumb, you want to restrict variables to the smallest scope necessary to do their job.

### Prefer initialization to assignment

In this case, moving `userInputString` inside of `main` would have one more beneficial effect: it's better to initialize than to create an uninitialized variable (a string, in this case) and assigning a value to it later. I'd prefer to use:

```
std::string userInputString(argv[1]);
```

...or:

```
std::string userInputString{argv[1]};
```

This means that `userInputString` contains the correct value as soon as it exists.

### Check `argc` before using arguments

You always want to check that `argv[1]` actually exists before trying to use it (and, by strong preference, print out a meaningful error message if it doesn't):

```
if (argc < 2) {
    std::cerr << "Usage: check <int>\n';
    return 1;
}
```

This tends to be more helpful than the default error message (e.g., `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`).

### Use meaningful return values

You return `0` from `main` (indicating success) regardless of the input. You't typically want to indicate failure when the input was bad:

```
        cout << "invalid input." << endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
```

### Avoid `std::endl`

`std::endl` flushes the output stream, which is rarely needed, and tends to be undesirable. In this particular case it doesn't make much difference, but I'd get in the habit of using `'\n'` when you want to print a new-line, so you won't accidentally use `std::endl` when you're producing enough output for it to make a real difference.

### Use standard algorithms where applicable

If you do decide to continue checking that the input is all digits, it's probably better to use `std::all_of` (or perhaps, `std::any_of`) instead of writing a loop to do the job:

```
std::string input(argv[1]);

if (std::any_of(input.begin(), input.end(), [](char ch) { return !isdigit(ch); }) {
    cout << "invalid input." << endl;
    return EXIT_FAILURE; 
}
```

Comment: `Prefer initialization to assignment` is enlightening. I have always declared all variables at the beginning. Thanks. I just did some reading on `endl vs \n`, is it possible for you to cite an example when `std::endl` would cause issues ? I cannot visualize the potential problem.

Comment: @iridescent: the problem is simple: `endl` flushes the buffer, which tends to be fairly slow. For example, look at the numbers shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1926432/179910